# CSS - li element set height

Tags: css

I am trying to build a navigation menu. Here are some pieces.

```css
#main-menu .nav-bar { list-style:none; margin-top: 40px;}
    #main-menu .nav-bar li { display:inline; padding:0 10px;}
    
      #main-menu .nav-bar li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      padding-left: 50px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: #333;
      display: inline-block;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
    }

        .nav-bar .nav-button-home a { background:url("home.png") no-repeat 0px -20px transparent;}
```

```html
     <nav id="main-menu">
         <ul class="nav-bar">
              <li class="nav-button-home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
         </ul>
    </nav>
```

What happens is that li element is not tall enough to show the picture.
Any idea how I can increase a height li element so will show the whole picture?

Thanks

Comment: When using css background, the image adjusts to its container and not vice versa. Alternatively, use an <img> if you want the container to be able to adjust.

Comment: might be wise to specify a height for your li and then use background-size:100%;

Comment: Yes, everything worked, thank you! I am posting my own code with a small problem. I am trying vote up, but my reputation is low.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to make your li stretch dynamically to the size of your background image. You can easily do the reverse however, set a definite height to your li, then set your background to 'contain'. This scales the image down to fit inside your li without clipping.

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwjfa5ff/6/)

css

```
  li {

height:180px;
width:240px;
background-image: url("http://assets.worldwildlife.org/photos/2090/images/hero_small/Sumatran-Tiger-Hero.jpg?1345559303");
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
border:1px solid #656565;
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
```

}

```
span {
    position:absolute;
    top:140px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    padding:10px 0 10px 0;
    border:1px solid #656565;
}
```

Comment: I see. How can I show it horizontally? I also want to show some text underneath of pictures.

Comment: @mark just add display:inline-block; to your li tags. There are a few different ways you can add text to the bottom of your images. I've updated the fiddle and my code snippets to show you how I'd do this.

Comment: try changing (span) top:140px to 180px too, see how that suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Remove background Property "transparent"

```css
#main-menu .nav-bar { list-style:none; margin-top: 40px;}
    #main-menu .nav-bar li { display:inline; padding:0 10px;}
    
      #main-menu .nav-bar li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      padding-left: 50px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: #333;
      display: inline-block;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
    }

        .nav-bar .nav-button-home a { background:url("home.png") no-repeat 0px -20px;}
```

```html
     <nav id="main-menu">
         <ul class="nav-bar">
              <li class="nav-button-home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
         </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     <style type="text/css">
    body { font-family: sans-serif; }

    #main-menu .nav-bar { list-style:none; margin-top: 40px; }
    #main-menu .nav-bar li { display:inline; padding:0px 30px; }

    #main-menu .nav-bar li a {
      height:48px;
      width:48px;
      display: inline-block;
      background-size: contain;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding-left: 25px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: #333;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
      position:relative;

    }

    .nav-bar .nav-button-home a { background:url("commons/imgs/prism/home.png") 0px -0px; }
    .nav-bar .nav-button-assets a { background:url("commons/imgs/prism/assets.png") 0px -0px; }
    .nav-bar .nav-button-alarms a { background:url("commons/imgs/prism/alarms.jpg") 0px -0px; }
    span {
        position:absolute;
        top:50px;
        left:0px;
        width:100%;
        text-align:left;
        padding:10px 0 10px 0;
    }

</style>

<nav id="main-menu">
     <ul class="nav-bar">
         <li class="nav-button-home"><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
         <li class="nav-button-assets"><a href="#"><span>Assets</span></a></li>
         <li class="nav-button-alarms"><a href="#"><span>Alarms</span></a></li>
     </ul>
</nav>
```

The only problem I have is that text center is not fully aligned with a center of an image.